# Are biur chometz, biur sheviis and biur maaser chovas habayis or chovas hagavra?

Tags: maaser-tithes, maseches-sheviis, biur-chametz

Just intuitively, seems to me like they would be chovas habayis. But would love to see any discussion, sources, etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site says, "Bedikas chametz, for example, is purely a chovas bayis, to ensure the home does not have chametz in it," but doesn't cite anything. https://dvarhalacha.com/hadlakas-neiros-7-where-to-light-1-introduction-1-klal-5-siman-10-erev-shabbos-s0134/

Comment: Seems to be an opinion on the books that biur chametz is also a chovas hagavra https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.436.3?lang=bi